# SSIS Package gets corrupted after importing from local machine

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

I have upgraded from **SQL Server 2016** to **SQL Server 2019** recently. Before that, I have used Visual Studio 2015 & SSDT on my local machine to create SSIS Packages and deployed them with SSMS 2016 onto the SSIS Server (File System).

After the server upgrade to 2019 I am now using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition with the extension "SQL Server Integration Services Projects (v3.15)". When I try to deploy the package with SSMS 18.10 from my local machine to the new SSIS Server the package can't be executed. When I manually copy the SSIS package onto the server and use the same SSMS 18.10 installed on the SQL server I can deploy them without any problems.

I have checked what happened to the package after the import from my local machine. It seems that some kind of server-side upgrade process kicks in and replaces all the SSAS processing tasks in the package with a strange task called **"SSIS.ReplacementTask"**, which gives me the error:

> The task with the name "Analysis Services Processing Task" and the creation name "SSIS.ReplacementTask" is not registered for use on this computer. Contact Information: ...

I can connect to my SSIS server with SSMS 18.10 without any error messages. However, when I check the DTEXEC version on my local machine, it still says that I am on version 13 (SSIS 2016). Could this be the cause of the problem?

**Update**
The TargetServerVersion is correctly set to 2019. Still either the SSIS Server or my local SSMS thinks it needs to change/upgrade the package.

I am slowly running out of ideas. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Hi, I don't know if you found a solution yet... I have the same issue. What i can say is that I have trouble to open my project with newer versions of Visual Studio. On some machine SSDT coexist peacefully and we can open maybe 2 versions of SSIS, on others we can only have one instance at a time... We tried to migrate it to the latest version with the VS assistant but it failed because of this replacement task. We are on the verge of migrating things manually by recreating SSIS packages in new environments...

Comment: My Solution: Switching from file system deployment to Integration Services database deployment was a wise decision. I now have enhanced capabilities to investigate failed package runs thanks to the comprehensive logging provided by the database.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the package `TargetServerVersion` property is set to `SQL Server 2019`:

- [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The TargetServerVersion is set to 2019. The package runs perfectly fine when I deploy it directly from the server instead of my local laptop. I can also copy the package from my local machine to the SSIS folder on the SQL server, which works. The problem is my local SSMS connected to SSIS of the server and using the "Import" function.

Comment: @MarcelPfeifer try to upgrade the SSMS on your local machine. It may work

Comment: Still the same after updating...